# Local projective transformations

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, projective-geometry

We know that is a map from a real projective space to itself, which sends real projective lines to real projective lines, is a real projective transformation. I am interested to know if there is a local version of this result. That is, given a local diffeomorphism of a real projective space, which sends projective lines to real projective lines, is it a real projective transformation of the space restricted to an open set?

Comment: Note that a map which sends lines to lines is a [collineation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation). An automorphism of the field underlying the projective space is a collineation but not a projective transformation. Prime example would be complex conjugation in the complex projective plane. So you might want to insert the word “real” somewhere in your statement.

Comment: yes, you're right! Thanks!